# How can i merge multiple result from multiple query in single json

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

i so intersted how i can merge result from two query in single json file?

> i have one query : Select * from student
>
> and my second query : select * from teacher

```
$result = array_merge($query1, $query2);
echo json_encode($result);
```

i have use `array_merge` but it not work, how can i fix this. Thanks for your help

Comment: you can use array_merge if u have convert json to array

Comment: merge first the result before encoding to json

Comment: hai, thanks for your answer. i am edited mya question. i want to create json from two result of two query, may i do this?

Comment: show your query1 array and query2 array .atleast sample array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your comment you have relationship between two tables so you just use single query to get merged result like this .

JUST use mysql  [`JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)

```
select * from student join teacher on student.teacher_id = teacher.id ;
```

> on condition should be changed as your need with your relatioship columns

Answer (score 0):

If your tables have same column count you can use UNION ALL in your query.

```
Select * from student
UNION ALL
select * from teacher
```

Comment: hai, tahanks for your answer but what if my table have different column? can i use Union too sir?

Comment: are you planning to get all the column in each of the table? or just some specific columns only? for example the name of teacher and the students only...
or can you just give an overview of your two table structure

Comment: hai @coriano yes i want to get spesific column of my tables.

Comment: is there any relationship between two tables ? @DennyKurniawan

Comment: @JYoThI yes sir, its in a relationship

Comment: then you just use join like this  *select * from student join teacher on student.teacher_id = teacher.id ;*   on condition should be changed as your need  with your relatioship columns @DennyKurniawan

Answer (score 0):

If the columns are different in the two tables, you an create an array with two elements, the first containing the results of the student query, and the second containing the results of the teacher query.

```
$results = array(
    'students' => $student_results,
    'teachers' => $teacher_results
)
```

If the two tables are related, IOW, there is a foreign key in one pointing to a record in the other, you would use one query that joins the two tables.

Answer (score 0):

First, change your query result to an array then merge both.